# get id in url form ajax call php

Tags: php, html, ajax, url

I need the id in url to make a mysql_query. The problem is that I need to make this from an Ajax call and $_GET['id'] apparently is not working.
Is there an easy way to free myself from this? 
Thank you :)

Here is my ajax call:

```
echo "<div id='loading_utilizadores' class='loading'><img src='".$CONF['HOME']."/images/structure/ajax-loader.gif'/></div>";
        echo "<div id='utilizadores'></div>";

        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
            echo "CarregaAjax(\"#utilizadores\",\"#loading_utilizadores\",\"".$CONF['HOME']."/superadmin/box_utilizadores_ajax.php\", \"GET\")";
        echo "</script>";
```

The ajax function:

```
function CarregaAjax(id,loading,page,method){

if(method=="GET"){

    $(document).ready(function(){

        //$(loading).ajaxStart(function(){
            $(loading).show();
            $(id).hide();
        //});

        $(id).load(page);

        $(loading).ajaxStop(function(){
            $(loading).hide();
            $(id).show();
        });

    });

}
else{

    $(document).ready(function(){

        //$(method).submit(function() {
            $(loading).show();
            $(id).load(page,$(method).serializeArray());
            $(loading).hide();
            return false;
        //});

    });

}
```

And the peace of html ajax call. In this page I try to make the $_GET['id'], but with no success.

```
if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $officeID =  intval($_GET['id']);
}
else
{
    $officeID =  0;
}

if(!isset($crm_users))$crm_users = new crm_utilizadores;

//$officeID = 12;
$resultGetUsers = $crm_users->getUsersByOfficeId($officeID);

$html = "<table class='table1' width='100%' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='1' border='0'>";

if(!empty($resultGetUsers)){

    $html .= "<tr>";
        $html .= "<td class='table_title1'>Utilizador</td>";
        $html .= "<td class='table_title1'>Telefone</td>";
        $html .= "<td class='table_title1'>Telemóvel</td>";
        $html .= "<td class='table_title1'>E-mail</td>";
        $html .= "<td class='table_title1'>Situação</td>";
    $html .= "</tr>";
}else{
    $html .= "<tr><td class='empty1'>não foram encontrados utilizadores registados neste cliente</td></tr>";
}

//finalizar a tabela
$html .= "</table>";
```

I guess I'm mising the point, right? :p

Comment: Unless I'm not reading this code correctly, this is the URL you're calling in AJAX: `/superadmin/box_utilizadores_ajax.php`  There is no `id` value, or any other value, in that URL.

Comment: I made the ajax function to load a file from php, in this case /superadmin/box_utilizadores_ajax.php. This file is suposed to write some HTML above HTML already written in other files which include this one. I use this technique of $_GET and it usually work. With this ajax call, is not working :/

Comment: It's "working" just fine.  The URL *doesn't have* the query string parameter you're looking for.  That would look something like this: `/superadmin/box_utilizadores_ajax.php?id=123`  The `$_GET` collection looks for query string parameters in the URL.  It will find it *if it's there*.  But, in your code, it's not there.

Comment: The problem is that when thatphp is is being executed, the url look something like this:
myurl/index.php?view=deleteOffice&id=12

Comment: Now you're talking about a different page entirely.  `index.php` and `box_utilizadores_ajax.php` are different pages.  Which one has the code which attempts to retrieve a value from the URL?  (The code shown in the question.)  You may be sending that value to `index.php` at some point, but according to the code posted in the question you aren't sending it to `box_utilizadores_ajax.php`.

Comment: In the index.php, I include the file that makes the ajax call (first sample of code in the question). That file include the /superadmin/box_utilizadores_ajax.php. Is in this file that I'm trying to get the id. Sorry man if I can't explain better, I am confused myself :/

Answer (score 0):

This code attempts to read the `id` value from the URL:

```
$_GET['id']
```

But *this* is the URL you're requesting:

```
/superadmin/box_utilizadores_ajax.php
```

As you can see, there is no `id` value (or any other value).  That would look something like this instead:

```
/superadmin/box_utilizadores_ajax.php?id=123
```

The value has to be on the URL in order for `$_GET` to read it.

---

Now, the page you're *currently viewing* may have that value in the URL you *previously requested*.  But the server-side code isn't looking at your screen or interacting with your web browser.  All it knows is the request that you send it.  And that request doesn't contain that value.

You can, when loading the page, put that value on the request.  In `index.php` read the `$_GET['id']` value and output it to the JavaScript code which is making that AJAX request.  *Technically* it could be something as simple as this, just to demonstrate:

```
"/superadmin/box_utilizadores_ajax.php?id=" . $_GET['id'] . "\", \"GET\")"
```

***However***, be aware of the dangers of outputting raw user input to the page.  This results in things like [XSS vulnerabilities](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).  Be mindful of what you're outputting to the page, but ultimately you need to output that value somewhere in order for that JavaScript code to send it to the next (AJAX) request.  (Or, alternatively, you could store the file server-side in session state or something similar.  Thereby removing the URL from the equation entirely.  There are pros and cons either way.)

---

In short, you need to include the value on the URL being requested if the page at that URL is going to read the value.  The code can only read values which are there.

Comment: still couldn't make it work. Give me one day to clear my head and think about this! But I am grateful for the help!

Comment: Actually, it has worked!!!

Thank you man, your help was really important to me! I will check how to prevent malicious user inputs.

Again, thank you very much!